# How do I add a template for account pages only?

Tags: magento-1.7, template, blocks, menu

I have a template that needs to be only on account pages and checkout pages.

I have got a menu in the local.xml that is shown when a customer is logged in but I want to show it only on certain pages aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target specific pages by using their respective handles.

Add the following to your `local.xml`

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="menu/block" name="custom_menu" template="custommenu/template.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>

<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="menu/block" name="custom_menu" template="custommenu/template.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>

<customer_account>
    <reference name="header">
        <block type="menu/block" name="custom_menu" template="custommenu/template.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account>

<customer_logged_out>
    <remove name="custom_menu"/>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Guessing the menu would be added in the `header` of your webshop this will add it to the cart, checkout and customer account section ONLY for logged in users.

I've used the `customer_logged_out` handle to remove the menu when a user is not logged in. Somewhat along the lines of what you've discribed in your question.

Now you can call the menu by adding the following code in your `header.phtml` where you want to display the menu.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom_menu');?>
```

Comment: Does this go into local.xml?

Comment: Yes it does, should have mentioned this :)

Comment: Will this automatically show in the header or will I need to call <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_account_menu_block') ?>?

Comment: You will need to call it. It will only be automatically added of a PHTML file has `echo $this->getChildHtml()` without a key in it.

Comment: So adding <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_account_menu_block') ?> into my header will call the block but only on account pages and checkout pages?

Comment: yes, that's correct

Comment: For some reason that does not work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10586/discussion-between-m-dunbavan-and-sander-mangel)

Comment: @Mdunbavan if the answer worked for you please flag it as accepted answer to close the question :)